# How would I make the letters rose gold colored?

Tags: color

I have a pink napkin with letters that are rose gold colored:

[image]

The problem is that the letters look too golden and not pink enough. If I try taking pictures of the napkin with better lighting, the pink napkin gets overexposed.

I tried using the strategy taught here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gpO2VNPJzw but I can't seem to find the right pink using just the Hue / Saturation method.

This is the color I'm looking for:

[image]

Is there a good method for changing the color to another color?

Comment: I do not understand, Are you taking the photos yourself or you are just editing existing photos to transform them?

Comment: The second photo has a black napkin, not a pink one. Are you trying to transform the first into the second?

Answer (score 2):

My tutorial here will likely help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4cl9U9RHUY its for different function but the same will work for you (I know because I just did it to confirm).

Basically:

- Switch to L*a*b color mode
- Select a point or two on the one you consider good and since its a different document jot them down
- Select similar lightness points on your version that you want to fix. IE: if you selected a mid brightness gold on the sample do the same on yours.
- Then just make a curves adjustment to fix them

Obviously you also need to mask or select the text as well. I didn't take the time to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It's simple:

[image]

There's a new top layer which is filled with a color picked from your goal image. The sample is taken from a mid-bright place.

The new top layer has blending mode Hue.

If you have the metallic parts as a separate layer, there's no problem to make a selection to delete the unnecessary color and keep the background intact. If your image is single layer, you must carefully draw the selection or layer mask or accept the color change of the paper, too. My version shows how much the paper get color.